# nsurl to uimageview does not show after parsing json array

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Well in my .m file I am doing the following:

I am fetching data over the web and store them in an NSMutable array by parsing json array. These data are images urls (images are on my server) and then I want to set them on my custom cell. each cell has 2 imageviews.

I am parsing the data correctly.
i do store them correctly.
I can see their values printed out and If i open them in a browser they are correct values.

If in my cell place static images from my resources I can see them.

But If i try to set them from the url I do not see anything.

here is my code:

For fetching data:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];
    images_url= [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary *alert in json ){
        NSString* image = [alert  objectForKey:@"image"];
        [images_url addObject:image];

    }
    [self.myTable reloadData];

}
```

where myTable is my synthesized TableView.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int i=[images_url count]/2;
    return i;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"ListTableCell";
    //this is the identifier of the custom cell
    ListsCell *cell = (ListsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    /*NSString *url_left=[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)];
    NSLog(@"Left url is:%@",url_left);
    NSString *url_right=[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2+1)];
    NSLog(@"Right url is:%@",url_right);*/  THEY ARE PRINTED HERE

    NSURL *url_left=[NSURL URLWithString:[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)]];
    cell.Left.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url_left]];
    NSURL *url_right=[NSURL URLWithString:[images_url objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2+1)]];



    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 81;
}
```

If I remove the reload data, then I do bot see their values and not the correct number of lines, so it is necessary.

So can anyone find out what is wrong in here?

Comment: it looks like you are getting the image correctly.  If you use a local image does it show?   You should check out apples example project 'lazy tables'.  It shows how to download images in background threads instead of in the main thread like you are doing.  better performance.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394

Comment: Yes it does show. Ok I will check the link. I also heard about egoimageloader. is it easier or not for someone new like me?

Comment: the way you create a custom cell, mainly cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0], is a different approach than what has worked for me.  Not sure if this is affecting it, but i've always had good luck using this tutorial on custom table cells. Slightly different approach.

Comment: http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-add-a-custom-uitableviewcell-to-a-xib-file-objective-c/

Comment: Well i don't know if it has to do with it but if my image changes from png to jpg it shows up. I thought that I could retrieve pngs, too.